# Bootstrap media-breakpoint-up($next) not working

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I've included in my project some template of scss mixins, variables, etc. from one repository. Guess it was this [link](https://gitlab.hashdash-group.com/witheasedev/argon_onetapbuytest/-/blob/e5c4c91883ae4a24fcf748df7e313ed6261b6da2/assets/scss/bootstrap/_navbar.scss)

My `navbar` has the following styles

```
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; // cannot use `inherit` to get the `.navbar`s value
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;

  .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

As you can see `flex-direction: column` (as it should be on mobile screen), for responsive navbar they have written the following css property:

```
 @include media-breakpoint-up($next) {
    @debug $next;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    .navbar-nav {
      flex-direction: row;

   ....
  }
```

And I guess `media-breakpoint-up($next)` should make my navbar to be responsive  and change `flex-direction` to `row` , but it is not working as I expected and it is always `flex-direction: column`. I've also debugged the `$next` variable `@debug $next;` and terminal shows `sm,md,lg,xl,null` and it seems like it should be correct.

Can someone help please ?

Comment: react or angular?

Comment: @chiragsolanki angular